# i get the data from 1st activity. in this 2nd activity, i try to input a value, so that y=beta0 +beta1*x. but when i input x, the result y is 0

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I get the data from the first `Activity`. In the second Activity, I try to input a value, so that 
`y = beta0 + beta1 * x`. But when I input `x`, the result `y` is 0.

This is my code:

```
public class PredictValue extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText et_x;
    Button btnPredict;
    TextView RegressionModel, ResultY;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.predict_value);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();

        String beta1 = bundle.getString("beta1");
        String beta0 = bundle.getString("beta0");

        et_x = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_preX);
        btnPredict = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_predict);
        RegressionModel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_model);
        ResultY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_predict_y);

        RegressionModel.setText("y = " + beta0 + "+" + beta1 + "x");

        btnPredict.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Editable editableValue_x = et_x.getText();

        float value_x = 0,
        result_y,
        beta1,
        beta0;

        Intent i = getIntent();

        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();

        beta1 = bundle.getFloat("beta1");
        beta0 = bundle.getFloat("beta0");

        if (editableValue_x != null)
        value_x = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x.toString());

        result_y = beta0 + (beta1 * value_x);

        //the calculation do here//
        ResultY.setText("y =" + result_y);
    }

}
```

This is part of Activity 1. I try to use this code to pass the data to activity2.

```
public void next (View nxt){
    Intent i = new Intent (this, PredictValue.class);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("beta1", ResultBeta1.getText().toString());
    extras.putString("beta0", ResultBeta0.getText().toString());

    i.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: What values for beta0 and beta1 have?  What does the debugger show you?

Comment: @Simon the values for beta0 and beta1 is from activity 1.

Comment: i input 10 x and 10 y. after calculation, i get beta0 and beta1.

Comment: You'd need to show the code from that activity as well (to see how you're bundling the information)

Comment: i try to pass beta0 and beta1 to this activity. so when i input x, it should be y= beta0 +beta* x and calculate the y.

Comment: That may be, but as the documentation states the getFloat() method "Returns the value associated with the given key, or 0.0f if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key." I suspect this is the case.

Comment: When you set beta0 and beta1 on the bundle, are you setting them as strings or floats? You must retrieve them in the same form as you set them or it's treated as a separate value. Try logging the retrieved values to verify you're retrieving what you expect. I noticed you're using getString() in one place and getFloat() in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the values from the bundle in the same form as you put them in. So in this case you need to change it to:

```
beta1 = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("beta1"));
beta0 = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("beta0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected you're putting strings into the first activity's bundle

```
extras.putString("beta1", ResultBeta1.getText().toString());
extras.putString("beta0", ResultBeta0.getText().toString());
```

And you are trying to extract floats

```
 beta1 = bundle.getFloat("beta1");
beta0 = bundle.getFloat("beta0");
```

which, as expected, are 0.

Comment: Yep. use putFloat instead of putString (careful: you need to validate your texts before you convert them to floats)